# How to use aggregate $lookup to join documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

routes.js

```
routes.get('/dataWithComment', async (req, res) => {
    await Admin.aggregate
    (
        [
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from:"Comme",
                    localField: "fname",
                    foreignField: "fname",
                    as:"profile_comment"
                }
            }
            // {
            //     $unwind: "$profile_comment",
            // },
        ]
    ).then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
})
```

profile_schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const pSchea = mongoose.Schema({
    fname:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    lname:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('pSchea', pSchea);
```

comment_schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cSchea = mongoose.Schema({
    fname:{
        type:String,
        ref: 'pSchea',
        required:true
    },
    comments:{
        type:String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('cSchea', cSchea);
```

--------------------------OUTPUT--------------------

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "620b53937c1ec7ca02df39c6",
        "fname": "abcd",
        "lname": "cdef",
        "__v": 0,
        "profile_comment":[]
    },
    {
        "_id": "620b56c8563caa82f0048d52",
        "fname": "asdfdsf",
        "lname": "fasdfdsfd",
        "__v": 0,
        "profile_comment":[]
    },
    {
        "_id": "620b56ef563caa82f0048d59",
        "fname": "fadsfasdf",
        "lname": "fasdfsdsfa",
        "__v": 0,
        "profile_comment":[]
    },
    {
        "_id": "620b585be26227fe4636b9c4",
        "fname": "asdddds",
        "lname": "fasdfdsf",
        "__v": 0,
        "profile_comment":[]
    },
    {
        "_id": "620ca22b84885b54861def87",
        "fname": "dafdfasdf",
        "lname": "asdfdsfdf",
        "__v": 0,
        "profile_comment":[]
    }
]
```

-----------------------------------Question---------------------------------

Why it is showing `'[]'` in `"profile_comment"`, I have also tried uncommenting `"$unwind"` but then it is just showing output like `'[]'`?
and what will be other method to do the same thing?

Comment: Use `await Admin.find();`. Same with each of the three database operations - as they are within an `async` function - the route handler. I think you dont need the `Promise.all`.

Comment: Ya I understood but can you solve the above edited one. I came at certain results.

Comment: The `$lookup` aggregate query result `"profile_comment":[]` is empty - it means there are no matching documents from the "join".

Comment: But the localField and the foreignField is same I have checked 2-3 times than what else can be the reason? I am using postman getting the result.